# What does "throw-out" mean when describing somebody's style of walking?

Tags: meaning, nouns, colloquialisms

In chapter VII of John Buchan's 1924 novel *The Three Hostages*, the following sentence occurs:

> He told me all kinds of things about her - how she was crazy about dogs, and didn't fear anything in the world, and walked with a throw-out, and lisped delightfully when she was excited. Altogether at the end of it I felt I had a pretty good notion of Miss Victor...

The young man thus describing his fiancée would obviously not be using pejorative terms, so I presume that *throw-out* is an approving description of her gait, more genteel than talking of hip-swinging or a wiggle. I also presume that the expression is a 1920s colloquialism.

I have searched for the phrase on-line, searched on Stack Exchange, looked in various dictionaries and books of phrases both physical and online, and I have come up with absolutely nothing to the point. Most references I have found are to throw-out as a verb. The few references to it as a noun phrase define it as an object that has been discarded, which is obviously not the meaning that Buchan intended. Can anybody suggest what a 1920s reader would have understood by it?

Comment: Don't forget that in 1924 the adoption of shorter skirts revealing women's legs in normal usage was very new, there had been a shortening which revealed the ankles before and during the first world war but the proper short skirts, and particularly the flapper dresses, were a real innovation. Perhaps a "throw out" related to the revealing of the leg.

Comment: Maybe: *walked with her chest thrown out*, as in a strut.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what Buchan meant, but I found [a similar reference](https://riders.co/en/wakeboard/boat/batwing), using “throw out” as a verb, in a description of a wakeboarding trick.

> Jump, tilt your shoulder — and entire frame — towards the boat, release your back hand and have your leading hand hold the handle at your hips. And immediately **throw out your feet**, up and diagonally (as if dancing the can-can).

So the quoted sentence *may* be saying that the woman walked with high kicks, as if she were dancing, or marching in a military parade.